# How to convert estimated time to string with ICU library

Tags: c++, icu

How to convert estimated time to string with ICU library?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, it sounds like you're misunderstanding the purpose of the ICU library. The ICU library is for basic Unicode support. An "estimated time" is just a time interval; the ICU lib doesn't care where you got it from.

Furthermore, "Relative time styles are not currently supported." i.e. ICU can't format time intervals.

Comment: ICU is for a _lot_ more than "basic Unicode support". Also worth noting that it now supports what the OP is asking for (though don't ask me how long it's done that, nor how to do it :P)